# Set height of two divs when one has a value of auto

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have two divs:

```
<div id="content">
</div>

<div id="navigation">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content{
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#navigation{
  width: 200px;
}
```

I have `#content` width set to `800px` and the height set to `auto`.

I would like to set the height of the `#navigation` to the height of the `#content` because the height of the `#content` will change depending on the stuff I put into it.

This is jQuery that I have already got, but with no luck:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var height = $("content").outerHeight;

    $("#navigaton").css("height", height+"px");

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `outerHeight` is a function and content is an id: `$("#content").outerHeight()`

Comment: Did you forget the `#` in `#content`?
`var height = $("#content").outerHeight();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some problems with your syntax.
I fixed them **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/p5Dr6/3/)**

```
 $(function(){
   var h = $("#content").outerHeight(true);
   $("#navigation").css("height", h+"px");       
 });
```

Since you were using [`outerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/), I used it too.
But in you could've also used [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) or [`innerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a parent container. For the navigation:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
```

No JS required

Comment: Also: Might wanna throw a left: in there to get them side by side

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an 'onload' event.

You should use '.height()'

OuterHeight: content height + padding + border

InnerHeight : content height + padding

Height: content height

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your script, you're missing the "#" in front of "content". Try changing it to $("#content").